# can't save video with opencv 3.1 windows

Tags: python, opencv

i'm trying to capture a video using opencv 3.1. I'm using the following code, but when I run it on pycharm, a small window opens (according to task Manager it has something to do with video compression - i can't really see what's in it) and when I close it I get the video preview. However, when I break the loop and finish the program I still get an empty video file. Any suggestions? Thank  you

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
height = int(cap.get(4))
width = int(cap.get(3)) 
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('C:\Users\Ba\Desktop\output2.avi', -1, 20.0, (width,      height))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: so i guess the probalm is the fact that the video compression window doesn't open

Answer (score 1):

Having experience only with OpenCV+Python on Linux it appears odd that you use -1 as encoding format instead of commented out fourcc variable.